# I'm getting error in interpolation of data

Tags: angular

The following code does not work. I've tried everything to make it work. It appears that angle 2 does not accept interpolation calling a direct variable.

```
@Component({
  template: ` <input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="name" #name="ngModel">
              {{ name }}
            `
})
export class ProductComponent {

    private name:string = '';
}
```

rather than 'name' I would have to use product.name.

that's right? but why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a conflict of variables

Replace `#name="ngModel"` with `#name2="ngModel"`